# Qt painter path not visible at zoom level

Tags: qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I'm using a customized QGraphicsView to display a connection diagram (just nodes and edges). At some zoom levels everything displays fine but as I zoom in just a little bit connection edges (drawn using QPainterPath) disappear. Everything else (rectangles, polygons, etc) draws, though. How can I stop edges from disappearing?

Here is the paint method of my edge object which derives from QGraphicsItem (mPath is a QPainterPath):

```
void GraphEdgeVisual::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->save();
    painter->drawPath(*mPath);
    // Arrow child will draw itself

    painter->restore();
}
```

The primary customization of the graphics view is to allow zooming in/out via mouse wheel. Here is the code I have for that:

```
MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    // taken from http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=QGraphicsView:_Smooth_Panning_and_Zooming
    setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);

    //Use ScrollHand Drag Mode to enable Panning
    setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);
}

/**
  * Zoom the view in and out.
  */
// taken from http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=QGraphicsView:_Smooth_Panning_and_Zooming
void MyGraphicsView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)
{
    setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);

    // Scale the view / do the zoom
    double scaleFactor = 1.15;
    if(event->delta() > 0) {
        // Zoom in
        scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    } else {
        // Zooming out
        scale(1.0 / scaleFactor, 1.0 / scaleFactor);
    }

    // Don't call superclass handler here
    // as wheel is normally used for moving scrollbars
}
```

Comment: Can you please post comprehensive code, so that we can execute it?

Comment: It will take a bit to get to a compileable example but I'll try put something together tonight.

Comment: So in the process of stripping down my program to a small example I discovered an error in how I was calculating the bounding rectangle for my edge QGraphicsItem subclass. Fixed this an now I get edges at all zoom levels :)

Comment: Maybe delete the question. I can't do it. Maybe you can.